# Storing user info from HTML forms to postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I want to store the user input from the html form, for example first and last name. And store these in my postgresql database.
I created the html file:

```
    <form  >
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
      <input type="submit" name="">
    </form>
```

I have created the model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have also connected the postgre database in the settings.py file. I am bit confused about how to connect the frontend and database. I think I need to add the model to the views.py and get the POST request to get the user input and store in the models. Please nudge me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: [This guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) from the official docs has everything you need. Read it from top to bottom :-)

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other commenters have said, you can easily find this online. Here's something to get you started:

```
def store_user_info_view(request):
    first_name = request.POST.get('fname')
    last_name = request.POST.get('lname')

    User.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
    return redirect('/')  # Or whatever you want
```

Bear in mind that you need to have a path in your `urls.py` file point to that view, and you need to make the `action` attribute on your form point to that path.

Good luck!

EDIT: I don't know if this is just an example of if you really are trying to create `User` objects. If you are really creating `User` objects, they are created with a special method which is `User.objects.create_user(...)` as opposed to just `create`.

Comment: What I am trying to make is like a news alert web app, that sends daily top news via email. So I want user to be able to 'subscribe' by submitting their email via the html form. I want to the email to be stored in the database, so that later I can collect the email address and send the email. Do I still need to have a path in the urls.py to point to the view? @Sam Creamer

Comment: Can you post your project structure here or send it to me? I can help point you in the right direction.